# AWS Amplify environment variables not working for NextJS app

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, environment-variables, aws-amplify, next-auth

I recently deployed my next application on AWS Amplify and learned that Amplify cannot access my environmental variables. However, if I use the .env file in my root directory for production, it works, but Amplify environmental variables are not working. I have tried changing build settings as per AWS amplify documentation.
Kindly help.

Build Settings

```
version: 1
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - env | grep -e MONGODB_URI >> .env.production
        - env | grep -e NEXT_PUBLIC_ >> .env.production
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: .next
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
      - .next/cache/**/*
```

And please let me know about this line if it can help
"To modify your app's build spec choose 'Edit'. Alternatively, you may download the YML file and deploy in the root of your repository to amplify.yml to override this setting."

How can i use yml file in my root directory to resolve this issue once and for all

[image]